# Value-Returning Function Debug Error - C++

Tags: c++, return-value, user-input

I am in a beginner C++ course. Here are the instructions for my assignment:

Write a program that calls a value-returning function that prompts the user to enter the weight of a person in pounds and then calls another value returning function to calculate the equivalent weight in kilograms. Output both the weights rounded to two decimal places. (Note that 1 kilogram = 2.2 pounds.) Format your output with two decimal places.

I thought everything was perfect. However, I am a getting a debug error, which is Runtime Check Error #3 - T. Please review my code and tell me what is wrong here. Remember, I am a beginner. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string get_date();
void student_heading();
float get_user_input(float);
float convert_weight(float);

int main()
{
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

string mydate;
float weight_lbs;
float weight_kgs;

mydate = get_date();
student_heading();
weight_lbs = get_user_input();
weight_kgs = convert_weight(weight_lbs);

return 0;
}

string get_date()
{
string mydate;
cout << "Enter today's date:";
getline(cin, mydate);
return mydate;
}

void student_heading()
{
cout << "*******************" << endl;
cout << "Student" << endl;
cout << "ID Number" << endl;
cout << "SYCS-135" << endl;
cout << "Assignment 6" << endl;
cout << "October 6, 2015" << endl;
cout << "******************" << endl;
}

float get_user_input(float lb_weight)
{
cout << "Please provide us with your weight, in pounds:";
cin >> lb_weight;
return lb_weight;
}

float convert_weight(float kg_weight)
{
float lb_weight;
kg_weight = lb_weight / 2.2;
return kg_weight;
}
```

Comment: Add some prints (or run in a debugger) to find out exactly how far you code gets.

Comment: Its always helpful to show the error that you get.

Comment: @John3136 After user input of the date and printing the heading function, the code stops.

Comment: @Ritesh It says Debug Error. Runtime Error #3 - T.

Comment: Right, so there would appear to be an issue with `get_user_input()` How many parameters is it expecting? How many are you passing?

Comment: @John3136 I am only passing one user input variable. I would like to pass the variable from get_user_input into convert_weight. Are you able to point out what's wrong?

Comment: No, you are passing 0 variables. Read your code!

Comment: That code should have never compiled if you declared a function that takes two arguments and you didn't pass any.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are calling weight_lbs = get_user_input();

You cant call get_user_input with no argument because you do not have any function like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues.

- Your function prototypes are not correct. The parameter in the braces have to contain the variable name as well as data type. So only `function(int)` is not enaugh, it should be `function(int MyVariable)`. So the error was caused by calling function, which didn't exist, because your function prototype was not correct (expected a parameter).
- Your `get_user_input()` function has a parameter which is not needed. The whole function should look like this:

  ```
  float get_user_input()
  {
      cout << "Please provide us with your weight, in pounds:";
      float lb_weight;
      cin >> lb_weight;
      return lb_weight;
  }
  ```
- Function for mass conversion can look like this:

  ```
  float convert_weight(float lb_weight)
  {
      return  lb_weight / 2.2;
  }
  ```
- Your main function then should look like this:

  ```
  int main()
  {
      cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

      string mydate;
      float weight_lbs;
      float weight_kgs;

      mydate = get_date();
      cout << mydate << endl;
      student_heading();
      weight_lbs = get_user_input();
      weight_kgs = convert_weight(weight_lbs);
      cout << weight_kgs << "Kg";

      getchar();
      getchar();

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Don't forget to change the function prototypes to:

```
float get_user_input();
float convert_weight(float lb_weight);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had that at first and I thought it couldn't be right. Thanks though.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to check this  thread as solved.